# gmock is not counting the call when EXCEPT_CALL ::Times()

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I am using cmake v3.19.2, gtest v1.10.0. I encountered this issue when i was building a class(let it be someClass) and tried mocking another class(otherClass) whose pointer object was in the same class(someClass) and tried seeing the number of times it calls the method. As i can see that method call isn't counted. I managed to isolate the issue:

***someClass.h:***

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H
#include "otherClass.h"

//has an object from the other class
class someClass{
    public:
        someClass( otherClass* oc )
            : toCheck{oc}
        {}
        float method_to_forward( int id ) const;
    private:
        otherClass* toCheck;
};

#endif
```

***someClass.cpp***

```
#include "someClass.h"

float someClass::method_to_forward( int id ) const{
    return toCheck->method_to_check(id);
}
```

***otherClass.h***

```
#ifndef OTHERCLASS_H
#define OTHERCLASS_H

class otherClass{
    public:
        otherClass( float val )
            :val{val}
        {}
        virtual float method_to_check( int id ) const;

    private:
        float val;
        int id;
};

#endif
```

***otherClass.cpp***

```
#include "otherClass.h"

float otherClass::method_to_check( int id ) const{
    return this->val;
}
```

***Main.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "otherClass.h"
#include "someClass.h"

class mockOtherClass: public otherClass{
    public:
        mockOtherClass( float val )
            :otherClass(val)
        {}
        MOCK_METHOD( float, method_to_check, (int) );
};

TEST( test_1, testOther ){
    float val{20.00};
    mockOtherClass mo{val};
    someClass sc(&mo);
    EXPECT_CALL(mo, method_to_check(testing::_)).Times(1);//.WillOnce(testing::Return(val));
    float retVal = sc.method_to_forward( 2 );
    ASSERT_EQ(retVal, val);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

***CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.2)
project( justTest VERSION 1.0 )

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(GMock REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${GMOCK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(testRunner 
Main.cpp
otherClass.cpp
someClass.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(testRunner
${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
${GMOCK_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
pthread)
```

***the faliure that i get***

> Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mo,
> method_to_check(testing::_))...
> Expected: to be called once
> Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

i am really sorry you had to go through all the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am really really sorry for wasting you guy's time the only issue was that there is a variant of MOCK_METHOD which is MOCK_CONST_METHOD(no of args) which works just fine. is there any other way of doing like if we want to write a mock of non const method we write MOCK_METHOD instead of MOCK_METHOD1 just the args change so is there any other such variant for the above method which works in the same way